# Dynamically loading modules inside Angular 2 modals

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a modal inside which i am trying to load component and their modules dynamically.
But I was not able to find a way yet in which i could do so. The component and the module that i am trying to load has angular 2 implementation as well. So it has to be compiled before it gets displayed inside the modal.I am using third party module angular2-modal for creating modal. The modal i am trying to create should be a reusable component. I will be exposing my modal as a node module to my client. Therefore i cannot directly import the required module, which is to be displayed inside my modal.I am using SystemJsNgModuleLoader for compiling the module but in this case it is searching for js file rather than TS.
I am using webpack for my compilation and bundling process.

Regards
Vasudev Gupta

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using the ng2-modal-dialog (link below). This npm package allows you to load the components into a modal pop up.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-modal-dialog

Note: if you are using systemJS for loading your files make sure you include the path to this npm library.